# Clearcase report needed by month and by users

Tags: clearcase

In IBM clearcase, I wanted to list all checkins by month and by users?

I have tried `cleartool lshistroy` but that did not do any good.

Comment: Thank you for wise words. I wasn’t looking for free code service. I have figured it out calling pearl script. My question was there an easy way to do in GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding a "statistic usage" tool natively provided with ClearCase:

- You can check (on a ClearCase Windows client) the [ClearCase reports](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_reports_use.htm). 
  See "[How Rational ClearCase Reports works](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_7.1.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_proj.doc/c_rpt_howworks.htm)". 
  But that might not be supported anymore with more recent version of ClearCase (8.x or 9.x)
- The other workaround would be to use a [`cleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm) command associated with a [fmt_ccase format](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm)

That is:

```
cd /path/to/my/view/myVob
cleartool find -all -exec "cleartool describe \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\" -fmt \"%d %u\""
```

That would give the date and user associated with each version of a vob, which you can then sort, generating your own report that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run

```
cleartool lshistory -all
```

and then add in the `-fmt` switch to format the output.  The `-user` switch can be used to list the operations by user.   There is a Perl script floating around out there which will do this for you.  It is not thrifty as it loops a few times over the output but it works rather nicely.   I'll post a link here if I find it.